# inserting figure or table affect \chapter and \section

Tags: tables, floats

I am using `scrreprt` with this preamble:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper,oneside, 
listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, titlepage, headsepline, DIV12,
]{scrreprt}
```

I have a document with `\chapter` and `\section` and if I try to include a figure or table like this:

```
\chapter{bla}
\section{interviews}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline Diese & Tabelle & ist \\ 
\hline zentriert & und  & verwendet \\ 
\hline vertikale & Trennzeichen &  .\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{test} 
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=2.0]{Bilder/logo_dhbw}
\caption{Das Logo der DHBW Karlsruhe}
\end{figure}
\section{test2}
```

then I get a huge problem. This causes LaTeX to create a new page with the chapter name bla and in addition the section test2 to be at the same place on top of the page. They mix together. This also ignores any layout formatting I had previously done for chapter, section etc.
`\section{test2}` is still displayed correctly after that.[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In fact, your `figure`s don't interfere with `\chapter` or `\section`, rather than your cahpter and section titles are too long to fit into the header properly which makes them overlap. According to your screenshot, the left side of your header yields the chapter title and the right side the section title. Consider redesigning your headers using [`scrpage2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) or [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

Comment: I would have added a MWE but my MWE does not show this problem unfortunately. If I delete figures or tables I have no problems with `\chapter` and `\section`. I reckon some configuration or package is interfering.

Comment: You can try methodically commenting out a portion and watch the effect. That way you will be able to isolate the offending part.

Comment: Do you need to restrict the placement of figures? Not including `p` prevents LaTeX from making float pages so makes it very likely that floats drift to end of document.

Comment: I found out which package is causing it: it is fancyhdr more accurate it is `\pagestyle{fancy}`. If I comment it out this does not happen.
@DavidCarlisle what do you mean with `p` preventing LaTex? I am fairly new to LaTex. Please explain to me. :)

Comment: `\begin{figure}[hbt]` allows latex to put the float `h` ere `b` ottom or `t` op of page but does not allow it to make a page just consisting of figures and tables (which is `p` ) usually it is best to not use the optional argument at all and just have `\begin{figure}`

Comment: Have a look at the `placeins` package. The package enables the `\floatbarrier` command. You can get some quite good control over where floats appear relative to section breaks, etc.

Comment: With just a snippet, we can't really help, particularly as the issue doesn't really seem to relate to floats at all despite the title.